# Could not find artifact com.wavefront:wavefront-spring-boot-bom:pom:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry

I am using `spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure` dependency for distributed tracing. Getting error while `mvn clean install -X`
Actual error message is `Could not find artifact com.wavefront:wavefront-spring-boot-bom:pom:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT in xxxxSnapshots`  i am using `settings.xml` file in inside .m2 folder.

i tried to exclude these `wavefront-spring-boot-bom`  dependency. but iam not able to see the `mvn dependency:tree` bcs of build failure. This is the repo link..https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies/1.0.0-M7/
and this is excactly what i added.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-M7</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
    <groupId>com.wavefront</groupId>
    <artifactId>wavefront-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>grails</id>
    <name>grails</name>
    <url>https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/</url>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>grails-plugins</id>
    <name>grails-plugins</name>
    <url>https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: did you tried to remove -bom from wavefront-spring-boot-bom?

Comment: Official snapshots are hosted here https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/com/wavefront/

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the followings:

1. Go to https://start.spring.io and generate a project with sleuth
2. Follow the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel) and add Sleuth-OTel (exclude Brave)
3. Please use the official repo (see the docs above) instead of third -party ones

Two extra tips:

1. Use `mvn verify` instead of `mvn clean install`
2. OTel is still in Alpha, it is not meant to be used in production (that's why SLeuth-OTel is an incubator project)